# casperjs.bat on windows fails with cannot find module cli.js error

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying out casperJS to run some automated tests. On windows. I followed this [installation guide](http://casperjs.org/installation.html#windows) but am stuck.

when I try to run a simple test from the command line like this:

```
casperjs.bat smoketest.js
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:/code/base/main/Shared/casperjs\modules\cli.js'
```

I checked, and the file cli.js does exist under the specified path.

I thought the problem could be the mixture of forward and backward slashes in the path, but I edited the bootstrap.js casper code to hard code the path and it made no difference - it still the cannot find module.

I'm have tried this using phantomJS version 1.9.0, and 1.8.2.
Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Has anyone had success running casper on Windows?

Comment: I've been smashing my head against the wall over this one. Same error, same problem. Phew. Thought it was just me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a [bug in PhantomJS 1.9.0](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11165) that does not allow for absolute path loading in Windows. Afaik, this should only be apparent if you are using a master build of CasperJS (v1.1).

This bug has been fixed, but is not yet in the Windows binary. You can compile it yourself if you'd like, but that can take quite a bit of time.

Comment: NOW you tell me!.. Stuck on this one for 3 days...sheesh:)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the master build of casper. With the latest released version, 1.0.2, it works fine.

Comment: so not every casperjs old version is matching towards phantomjs .... The version should be noted first which one that works towards one another.... do you have about that notes @GarethOwen ?

Comment: No, no notes - sorry. I think I just used all the components from the same casper download?